# How to "return twice" (two properties) from an AngularJS factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very basic question here, but how can I return more than one property from an angularJS factory? I realize that in my code, only the first return will run and only the message will be passed to the other scopes. What is a way around this?

app.js

```
practice.factory('Data', function(){
    return {message: "I'm data from a service"};
    return {number: "twenty"};
});

practice.controller('FactoryOneController',['$scope','Data', function($scope, Data){
        $scope.data = Data;
}]);

    practice.controller('FactorySecondController',['$scope','Data', function($scope, Data){
        $scope.data = Data;
}]);

<div ng-controller="FactoryOneController">
        <input ng-model="data.message">
        {{data.message}}
        <input ng-model="data.number">
        {{data.number}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="FactoryOneController">
        <input ng-model="data.message">
        {{data.message}}
        <input ng-model="data.number">
        {{data.number}}
</div>
```

index.html

Comment: Pretty basic i guess.. :) Just `return {message: "I'm data from a service", number: "twenty"};`

Comment: Only one *value* can be returned. So put *more properties* into the *single returned object-value*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the things and return a single object with multiple keys!

So, instead of doing:

```
practice.factory('Data', function(){
    return {message: "I'm data from a service"};
    return {number: "twenty"};
});
```

...do this:

```
practice.factory('Data', function(){
    return {message: "I'm data from a service", number: "twenty"};
});
```

Then, later on in your Controller, you could do something like:

```
$scope.data = Data;

doSomething($scope.data.message);
doSomething($scope.data.number);
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is a general JavaScript function concept and not specific to Angular.js